# RemotePlaybackClient resume session on Chromecast

Tags: sessionid, chromecast, resume

I am trying to use the RemotePlaybackClient to resume a Chromecast session created by the same Android app.  I'm able to use this RPC vs the full Cast SDK to play, pause, resume, seek, and stop playback on the Chromecast device.  My current test is in closing the Android app and using the sessionId from the session to try to reload the app and resume control of the playback.  Upon closing the Android app, we are not terminating playback or the session, it keeps going.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// attempt resume
mRemotePlaybackClient = new RemotePlaybackClient(getApplicationContext(), ccRoute);
// ccRoute is the selected ChromeCast RouteInfo device - same as previous
System.out.println(mRemotePlaybackClient.isSessionManagementSupported()); // true
System.out.println(mRemotePlaybackClient.hasSession()); // false
mRemotePlaybackClient.setSessionId(saved_sessionId); // saved_sessionId is the sessionId saved from the mRemotePlaybackClient.play command in success reply.
System.out.println(mRemotePlaybackClient.hasSession()); // true
mRemotePlaybackClient.startSession(null, ccStart); // callback returns error 0
mRemotePlaybackClient.setStatusCallback(ccSessionStatus); // callback returns error 0
```

I've asked some others familiar with the RemotePlaybackClient and the Chromecast, including those within Google but did not get an answer.  Also, I seem to be seeing some of the same issues @Commonsware is seeing in that some callbacks don't reply at all.  In addition, with images, metadata is not returned and the status callback returns an error whereas video returns ok (position info etc).

Really, I'd just like to resume the session for now vs having to wire up the full Cast SDK.

Comment: startSession() always starts a new session, regardless of your "setSession()" call earlier (it uses ACTION_START_SESSION action).

Comment: I've tried with and without the .startSession() - how should we code to resume a previously running session for the Chromecast using the RemotePlaybackClient?  Example code from Google would be great.