# RemotePlaybackClient - Resume session

Tags: android, session, casting, google-cast

I am trying to implement a sample application using the [Media Router API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html) and the [RemotePlaybackClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/RemotePlaybackClient.html) class. I do not want to implement Google Cast SDK (simply because I want to support other remote devices than Google Cast ones).
Everything works quite fine until I want to retrieve the session currently playing on the remote device.

By that I mean that for example, I have a mobile device A casting to a specific remote player (RM) with my sender app. If I kill my app, then launch it again, how can I retrieve the info of the current playback session on the remote device ? The same situation occurs if I try to select the media route from another mobile device B with the same application.

Also, how should this be implemented on MediaRouterProvider side ?

When you use Netflix for example, it is able to retrieve info of the currently playing session, up to the item currently playing.

There is not so much documentation on the subject, and the [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRouter) provided by Google do not seem to implement this feature.

Fling can also be implemented using RemotePlaybackClient, and specifies at the end of their [online doc](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/fling/docs/using-amazon-fling-with-android-mediarouter) that some callbacks are just not called at all by Cast devices (@CommonsWare also noted that).

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676224/remoteplaybackclient-resume-session-on-chromecast) subject, but no answer to this specific situation has been provided.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

**Edit:** Basically, I am trying to join the current session from another device / instance (feature is available for the Cast SDK). How can I do that using the media router provider ? There is no application id using only the media router...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are talking about (i.e. joining an on-going session) is a Cast feature and not supported/covered by Media Router. The reason that apps such as Netflix can do that is because they are using the Google Cast SDK.

Comment: Okay, so do you know how this feature can be replicated using only MediaRouter, for the ChromeCast for example ? Is there any special intent that I can pass to the cast mrp for example ? I have a basic idea of how I can code a "join on-going session" using my custom mrp, but I wonder if there is any workaround to do that with the chromecast & mediarouter ?

Comment: MediaRouter framework is not built to address that and doesn't have a concept/notion of "application", for example.